How to view two different files side by side
I know you can select Window->Editor->Toggle Split Editor to view the same file in two different windows but how do you view different files in separate windows side by side

Drag the tab for the editor you want on the right to the right half of the editing pane and watch for it to draw a highlight around that area, then drop.
